# disable an input type in base of his value

Tags: html, css, jsp

i got this code :

```
<%
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_atte_old; i++) {
%>
        <TD class="tb" align=center>
            <INPUT class="txt_opz" type="text" style="width:40;" id="hDett_Sin4<%= i %>" name="hDett_Sin4<%= i %>" maxlength='2' value="<%=DataResultForm.getValueHTMLEncode( "hDett_old_risp_"+i )%>">
        </TD>
<%
    }
%>
```

the value is returnet from a stored procedure, how can i disable dinamically this input type if, for example his value is "hello"

HTML+CSS way is preferred, if possible (not using javascript)

Comment: You need to give more information. Do you only want to disable if it's one value or multiple?  Are you trying to disable using javascript or html + css?

Comment: @im1dermike html + css would be preferred but JavaScript can be ok if it's unpossible in the previous way. every input type in the for statement must be disabled/enbaled in base of his value.

Comment: even if i don't know if is possible anyway, without javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use java condition:

```
<% String val = DataResultForm.getValueHTMLEncode( "hDett_old_risp_"+i );%>
<input value="<%=val%>" <%= val=='hello'?'disabled':'' %> />
```

Comment: if i do:

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript> 
<% var val = DataResultForm.getValueHTMLEncode( "hDett_old_risp_"+i );%>
</SCRIPT>

obv it gives error cause is not possible open <%%> tag in javascript, and if i do simply

<% var val = DataResultForm.getValueHTMLEncode( "hDett_old_risp_"+i );%>

it gives error cause var is not a variable type. how can i resolve?

Comment: Sorry, I mix `jsp` with `jade` in my head) Wait a second)

Comment: Just write correct java statements around this. I change answer.